# how to use auto increment in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key, mamp, auto-increment

Super beginner question here about MySQL. I am following a book and learning how to create tables and populate them with data. I have so far managed to create a few tables and I understand the auto increment idea and the primary key idea etc... I have done this successfully with the terminal so far.
Now I want to learn how to use phpMyAdmin to do the same. I can manage to create the tables. My table (forums) has two columns 'forum_id' and 'name'. The forum id is a primary key and has auto increment checked. When I try to populate this table, the panel has two text input fields accordingly, one for each. What I don't understand is why is it even asking me to fill the 'forum_id' column. I thought it was understood that if it's a primary key and has auto increment checked, it should start at one and precisely auto increment by itself. That is what happens when I do the same using the terminal. Thank you for your time and sorry if this is basic.

--------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you for your answers. You are telling me to leave it blank and that was also my first thought, but when I leave it blank, I get this result: INSERT INTO forums (forum_id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'MySQL'), (NULL, 'PHP'); -is this right? the values appear to be "NULL"

Comment: Check my latest answer about your edit @Paul

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for you to send "forum_id" data when you insert the column data's you want to add. If you send it null or don't even send it at all, it'd automatically give it an integer based on the auto_increment value on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I leave it blank, I get this result: INSERT INTO `forums` (`forum_id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'MySQL'), (NULL, 'PHP'); -is this right? the values appear to be "NULL".

Comment: don't input forum_id at all. 
INSERT INTO forums (name) VALUES ('MySQL');

Comment: I am trying to do this using the interface, so filling the text fields etc... If i just ignore the text field for forum_id like you say and just fill the text field for name, then the table gets populated, but when I try to see what the table looks like using the terminal, the forum_id column is populated pretty randomly. For instance, my first entry will be 1, then the next will be 8, then 11...

Comment: Have you ever deleted some rows?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave auto_increment field empty and insert the new row, it will automatically add it with auto_increment value.

Answer (score 0):

This all has to do with your auto_increment value. You can add entries for forum_id 10, if your still at auto_increment count 1. If you leave the field blank, it will automatically fill in an integer.